# insert a div into header based on screen size?

Tags: jquery, insert, media-queries, screen-size

I have a div that works with a shopping cart plugin that displays the cart in the sidebar.

The website I am building is responsive and In the designs the "Items" div gets moved into the header of the site when the screen size is below 1024px

I tried just hiding and showing the divs with media queries but they both have the same ID, so what I would like to do is say at 1024 have "Items" in the sidebar and if the screen is resized below that, remove "Items" from the sidebar and add it to the header.

Is this possible?

Sorry if this seems like an easy fix,

Comment: You should not put the same id for different elements. Id should be used once.

Comment: That is the problem, there is an ajax cart that is hooked up to the id "items" that displays the items in the cart.
If I changed the name to say "items1" and "items2" the cart will not work.
So I think I need to remove the origional "items" div from the sidebar in tablet sizes and add it to the header, and vice versa?

Comment: You could .append() one of them to the document depending on user window size. I added code below, instead of showing and hiding simple append it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (untested, but should give you a general idea of an approach). Basically, it will check on resize for the windows size. If its less than 1024 the #items div will be removed and appended to the #header. Else, it will be re-appended to the #sidebar, assuming it was already appended to the header.

```
    function itemsToHeader(){


        $items = $('#items');

        if( $(window).innerheight() < 1024 ){

            if( $('#header').find('#items').length <= 0 ){
                $items.remove().appendTo('#header');
            }

        }else{
            if( $('#header').find('#items').length > 0 ){
                $items.remove().appendTo('#sideBar');
            }
        }

    }

    $(window).on('resize', function(){

        itemsToHeader();

    });

    itemsToHeader();
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that does make sense I will give that a try.
the items div was originally in the sidebar though.

I am a little unsure of what the setInterval function does though?

Comment: for simplicity's sake I've removed it, but essentially it would throttle the code from firing the itemstoheader() function hundreds of times while you are resizing your window, down to once per 100 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could check window width with jQuery and depending on size show and hide essential div.

```
if($(window).width() >= 1024) {
      $("#div1").show();
      $("#div2").hide();
} else {
      $("#div1").hide();
      $("#div2").show();
}
```

Comment: The only problem with that is that the id "items" is connected to this cart that was written by someone else.
And so they divs have to have the id "items" for the cart to work.